# Firebase orderby() with equalTo() returns zero items

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this rule in my firebase database

```
"Item":{
    "$userId": {
    ".write": "auth != null && $userId === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

I have this data

```
Item
 nXQw4a2jlMg34567811glaTD0bE2
   -KNJLSxfR_S8AeLj0v7d
     height:20
     id:-KNJLSxfR_S8AeLj0v7d
```

When i write the below query, everything is ok.

```
mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.ITEM);
  query = mDataBase.orderByChild("userId/height").limitToLast(2);
```

But the below query returns zero

```
public void getItems(String key){
//key is -KNJLSxfR_S8AeLj0v7d
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.ITEM);
reference.orderByChild("userId/id").equalTo(key).addValueEventListener(new MyEventListener());

}
```

My listener

```
 private class MyEventListener implements ValueEventListener{

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if(dataSnapshot != null){

   Log.d("size is "+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) // returns 0
   for(DataSnapShot entry: dataSnapshot){
     Item item = entry.getValue(Item.class);
     Log.d("height is "+ item.getHeight())
   }

  }

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}

}
```

Why is it returning zero and already i have data in my firebase Db?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small problems with your code:

1. There is no child `userId`, that you are trying to order/filter on: `orderByChild("userId/height")`. So that means the result will be empty.
2. You cannot loop over a snapshot (I'm surprised that even compiles). Instead you should loop over its children: `for(DataSnapShot entry: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {...`
3. You're using a query, but your code would be more efficient and a lot more scalable if you'd simply look up the item by their key: `reference.child(key).addValueEventListener(...`